# How to create settings option in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I tried searching this question in google but results were "how to enable setting in wordpress", "how to change wordpress settings"  etc. So, I thought of asking it here.

My question is: How to create setting option so individual users can select different settings like site colors for their browser or account ? I found out that I should create  a module but I don't know how to create it. So, I need  a help!

I just need the concept or simple example, I can figure out the rest.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I am not asking to create a wordpress plugin. I need basic concept for my php website.

Comment: this is not a trivial thing you ask.  I can tell you that any response to a request on a server is text.  Those images you see, are just text.  Those files, just text.  Those css files, again just text.  What makes that text special is the headers ( specifically the content header) I say this because it's entirely possible to replace your CSS file with a PHP file with the proper header.  Let that sink in a bit.

Comment: I am trying to make setting option in php.

Comment: If you replace the `.css` with a `.php` file then you can write whatever you want in the CSS file when it's loaded from the server.  Things such as color variables, padding, whatever you want.  Can all be dynamic.

Comment: For example: if you are a user and you select site color red the site color should change to red but only for your browser(account).

Comment: `I am trying to make setting option in php.`  That's the least of your problems. And you don't want options you want User Meta data, because it's specific to a user.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta  I could create a plugin for you, but I don't code for free, and Stack Overflow is for specific programing problems, not building wordpress plugins for you.  Which is why I voted to close this.

Comment: You can save these user based settings on DB avoid saving on settings file. It will you easy and different use will have different settings. Reason you got getting "how to enable setting in wordpress" because wordpress is the most popular for building website and easy to use.

Comment: No I dont want you to make a plugin I already said I just need basic concept.

Comment: And I don't want to create setting plugin for wordpress but for my own made site with php and jquery.

Comment: As @ArtisticPhoenix told, you can save all your setting in .php and can save configuration or settings.

Comment: @Lavanya Pant Can you please explain in detail how to store details for individual users.

Comment: There can be 2 approach. 1) Create a settings file include all user settings to one. 2) you can have different settings file for different user and one master settings which will include all user settings and this settings you can include wherever you want.

Comment: @Lavanya Pant How should I store them ? In cookies or database?

Comment: @BestBibek  If you have user login you can save them on database or else you can save as cookies.

Comment: Yes I have login system and table users with id,fullname,username,status and registered_date should I add a new column called 'settings' ??

Comment: if you have login u can save on db.